# Intermediate values between two numpy arrays from a given position

Tags: python, numpy

I have two monodimensional numpy arrays, which are integer representations of wave forms at different "time" points

```
first = array([0, 16, 24, -32, ...])
last = array([0, -16, -24, 32, ...])
```

Each wave array has an index, and I need to compute intermediate values between those values at different points. For example, if the `first` is at index 0 and `last` is at index 3, I need to compute positions at 0.25, 0.50 and 0.75, giving these arrays:

```
valuesAt25 = array([0, 8, 12, -16, ...])
valuesAt50 = array([0, 0, 0, 0, ...])
valuesAt75 = array([0, -8, -12, 16, ...])
```

Unfortunally, the only function I found is `numpy.percentile`, which doesn't work as I need, since it computes the percentile based on the lowest value.

It seems that I can do something with `scipy.interp1d`, but since I'm releasing the program as a bundle for Windows and MacOS I'd prefer to avoid adding the whole scipy package just for one function.

I can compute values manually, but it would take much more time (each array has 128 values and there can be up to 30 permutations), and I wasn't able to find other functions in numpy. Also, I might need to compute those values on the fly in the future, while other waves are already playing in the audio buffer, so pure python computation is not advised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define your own function:

```
import numpy as np

def percentile(a, b, percentile):
    return (1-percentile)*a + percentile*b

a = np.array([0, 16, 24, -32])
b = np.array([0, -16, -24, 32])

valuesAt25 = percentile(a, b, 0.25)
valuesAt50 = percentile(a, b, 0.5)
valuesAt75 = percentile(a, b, 0.75)
```

Comment: Wow. That's neat and easy... And it works! I really didn't think about this (I have not much experience with numpy yet). I'll make some further tests, but initial results are promising. If everything checks out, I'll mark as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the scipy package and want to have a fast execution of your programm, you should try the cython module. There you can build your own interpolation module and then translate it to C Code, which gives you speed improvment. For example something like this:

```
cimport cython
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
cdef double interpol_2D(double[:] x_ax, double[:] y_ax, double x_val):
    cdef int i, pos, length
    length = len(x_ax)
    for i in range(length):
        if x_val <= x_ax[i]:
            pos = i-1
            break
    if pos < 0:
        pos = 0
    if pos > length-2:
        pos = length-2
    return y_ax[pos]+(y_ax[pos+1]-y_ax[pos])/(x_ax[pos+1]-x_ax[pos])*(x_val-x_ax[pos])
```

Maybe you've to edit the algorithm part which indicates the position of the two relevant values for the calculation. I don't now how the values are organized in your array.

Comment: Thanks; I didn't think about using cython (never used before, in fact). I will think about it for other uses, since it seems that an easier way is actually working: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51498858/2001654